# ArangoDB Corruption Bad table magic number

Tags: arangodb, rocksdb

we're using ArangoDB 3.3.5 with RocksDB as a single instance.

we did a shut down of the machine where arangod is running, and after reboot the service didn't come up again with the following warning:

```
Corruption: Bad table magic number
```

Is there a way to repair the database? Or any other ways to get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the RocksDB files. Please try to start specifying `--log.level TRACE`, store the log file, open a github issue and attach the corresponding logfile.
Cheers.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the issue can be found here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/5539